# Entity Framework 6- Dynamic entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

My company has 100’s of databases with few thousands of entities including Tables, SP and Views.

I am creating a generic Data layer using Entity Framework 6 for my company’s ad hoc projects such that developers don’t have to bother about the underlying database.

My project contains Empty Data Model (.edmx).

Now based on the user selection I need to set the connection and get the entities at run time. Once these entities are registered, I need to provide a collection of data to the caller.

For example: A developer invokes the method from my class and pass entity name as enum string .say … “Entity.Orders”

Here.. my code knows that “Orders” belong to Database named “Sales” which is on “SalesBox” server.

My code now sets up the connection to “Sales” database, get the rows from “Order” table, create a List collection (or any appropriate) and return the collection to caller.

Is this all possible using EF 6? If yes How?